# Do Ajax Search after 3 characters

Tags: javascript, ajax, search

How could it be done that I make an Ajax Search after the user typed in 3 characters?
I'm not that expert in javascript, but here's my HTML file so far:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="searchField" name="searchField" placeholder="...">
</form>

<script>
    $('#searchField').searchbox({
    url: 'components/search_ajax.php',
    param: 'q',
    dom_id: '#searchResult',
    delay: 0,
    loading_css: '#spinner'
    });
</script>
```

At the moment the search is called just when the backspace button is pressed (then all of my database entries are represented because there is a match-search with no character).

Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to let us know which plugin you're using, I have a feeling it is [this](https://github.com/rpheath/searchbox/blob/master/searchbox.js), if it is, change:

```
process: function(terms) {
```

to

```
process: function(terms) {
  if(terms.length < 3) return;
```

But you should also limit this on your server side, otherwise I can just go directly to your script to view all entries. You can do this at the top of your `php` file with:

```
if(strlen(trim($_GET['q'])) < 3) return; // only basic, would need more checks
```

Comment: your feeling was right. and your solution works well (on both side, javascript and php file). thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$('#searchField').change(function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 if(value.length>= 3){
    ajax_search();
 }

});

function ajax_search(){
  $('#searchField').searchbox({
  url: 'components/search_ajax.php',
  param: 'q',
  dom_id: '#searchResult',
  delay: 0,
  loading_css: '#spinner'
  });
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `$('#searchField').searchbox()` will be initialised on `searchField` each time you change the input.

Comment: what he needs is to start the search depending on the length of input. ``searchbox()`` will be initialised here also, but only after the user does his input of length 3. he doesnot mention what he is using, what i gave is just the simple code regardless of any plugin

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if you continue to reinitialize `searchbox()` you're gonna have a bad time mmmkay

Comment: i think, searchbox should be reinitialised, right? if i input ``lond`` it cannot find london, then i will continue typing with ``london`` then it should also search in the database again, so reinitialising makes sense i think

Comment: thanks. but i've done your solution on my own yesterday and it didn't worked because like Prisoner mentioned searchField would be initialised every time I type in a character.

Comment: ok, glad that you found a solution no matter who helped you :D